# How to use monte carlo to plot histogram?

Tags: r, montecarlo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWoh1.png)I am trying to run a monte carlo simulation but don't know how to write the code. I need to plot a distribution of rolling sixes in 10 rolls of a die without using rbinom.

I have tried using the replicate function but my histogram does not look right.

```
dat <- replicate(n=10, expr = sum(runif(10, min=0, max=1)>1/6))
hist(dat, prob=TRUE)
```

I think since it is a simulation I am expected to have 10,000 trials (according my professor) but I don't know where to put the number of trials.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVsj5.png)

Comment: Try n = 10000 to change how many trials.

Comment: And perhaps `hist(dat, prob=TRUE, breaks = 1:10)`

Comment: I added another image to show what happened when I ran that code. That does not make sense as we wouldn't expect the frequency of rolling a 6 to be so high, as it appears on the graph.

Comment: Can you use `sample()`? E.g. `sample(1:6, 10, replace=TRUE)`. I believe it uses uniform sampling, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Changing `1/6` to `5/6` should also do the trick